# Why can't I inject a service into Angular factory/injector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an authentication service (AuthenticationService) I use for calling out to a WEB API. I recently have learned about interceptors. I want to create an interceptor to intercept requests and modify headers based on the state of the AuthenticationService.

I am having some sort of problem with injecting the AuthenticationService into my interceptor. When I do this, my page is broken. I see things like {{MyVariableName}} instead of the value. Also submitting a form does not work. Nothing happens on a button click.

I have no idea what the problem is, because I cannot find any error message or anything to indicate what the problem is. Nothing is in the console. The page is just broken. If I remove the AuthenticationService from the interceptor, everything works again. Below is my interceptor code:

```
app.factory('authInjector', ['AuthenticationService', function (AuthenticationService) {
var authInjector = {
    request: function (config) {
        config.headers['x-session-token'] = 'test'; 
        return config;
    }
};
    return authInjector;
 }]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInjector');
}]);
```

"app" is defined in another JavaScript file (app.js). This also where AuthenticationService is. The service is declared like this:

```
app.service('AuthenticationService', function ($http) { ... }
```

My scripts are loaded in the following order:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/injector.js"></script>
```

I also tried using $injector in my interceptor code, but it was worthless. I got an error stating that $injector was undefined at run time.

```
var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthenticationService');
```

Can anyone tell what my interceptor's problem is with AuthenticationService?

Thanks

Edit: Requested information:

```
<html ng-app="MyAppName">
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('MyAppName').controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, AuthenticationService) {

var app = angular.module('MyAppName', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

There is no error present in the console.

Comment: check/show your `ng-app` tag and the line in each javascript containing `var app=angular.module(...)`

Comment: There's an error in your web browser console. What does it say?

Comment: Also show where you actually declare the module `MyAppName`. That last line simply references it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `circular dependency` in your interceptor. You're attempting to inject a service that is using `$http` while at the same time attempting to configure the `$httpProvider`.

One solution would be to manually inject the `authService` inside the `request` property of the interceptor.

```
app.factory('authInjector', ['$injector', function($injector) {

  var authInjector = {
    request: function (config) {
      var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService');
      // Do whatever you need to do with AuthService
      config.headers['x-session-token'] = 'test'; 
      return config;
    }
  };
  return authInjector;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **authInjector**:

```
var AuthenticationService = $injector.get('AuthenticationService');
```

change that:

```
app.factory('authInjector', ['AuthenticationService', function (AuthenticationService) {
```

to:

```
app.factory('authInjector', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
```

order of scripts:

```
<script src="~/app/app.js"></script> // create the app and dependencies
<script src="~/app/authentication.service.js"></script> // create the authentication service
<script src="~/app/auth-injector.service.js"></script> // create the interceptor factory
<script src="~/app/app.config.js"></script> //push the interceptor to httpProvider
```